# What is the keyword to use in javascript to get i18n translation using angular-translate library?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have implemented i18n for the Angularjs project.

for example here is the sample of controller code:

```
var MultilingualApp = angular.module("MultilingualApp", ["pascalprecht.translate"]);

MultilingualApp.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations("US_EN", {
    "GREETING": "Hello !",
    "DESCRIPTION": "This is a demo app for multilingual support.",
    "LBL_SWITCH": "Click here for switching language between spanish to english",
    "CLICK": "Click"
  });
  $translateProvider.translations("SPANISH", {
    "GREETING": "Hola !",
    "DESCRIPTION": "Esta es una aplicacion de demostracion para soporte multilingue",
    "LBL_SWITCH": "Haga clic aquí para cambiar el idioma entre espanol al Ingles",
    "CLICK": "Click"
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage("US_EN");
});


MultilingualApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $translate) {
  console.log("hello tehre")
  $scope.changeLanguage = function () {
    var language = $translate.use();
    if (language === "US_EN") {
      $translate.use("SPANISH");
    } else {
      $translate.use("US_EN");
    }
  };
});
```

here is the HTML code where we are using **{{'GREETING'|translate}}** keyword to get the translation done:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bower-angular-translate/2.7.1/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<div ng-app='MultilingualApp' ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
    <div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
        <h3>{{'GREETING'|translate}}</h3>
        <p>{{'DESCRIPTION'|translate}}</p>
        <label>{{'LBL_SWITCH'|translate}} </label>
        <button ng-click='changeLanguage()'> {{'CLICK'|translate}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I do the button click all the HTML text are converted.

The problem is I am not able to translate the javascript text.

Is there any keyword which is used to translate the javascript texts?

**Edit**

When I say the javascript text it means there are some alerts (text messages) that I am sending from javascript to HTML.

for example:

```
function errorCallback(errorResponse) {
      $scope.loginParams.errorText = 'The username and password that you entered don\'t match.';
      $scope.SigningIn = false;
}
```

in the above example how can we convert the error text **The username and password that you entered don\'t match.**

Comment: What “JavaScript text”?

Comment: @deceze I have edited the question. see the edit section.

Answer (score 1):

That’s what you use the `$translate` service for.

```
MultilingualApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope, $translate) {
  $translate('Error!').then(msg => $scope.message = msg);
});
```

Comment: Should I have to write this piece of code for each line of text in the same file ?

Comment: No. Whenever you need to translate a string in a controller or service, you inject the `$translate` service and use it to get a translation for your string. That’s all.